# Inheriting F# Record

Tags: f#

My understanding is that F# records are non-sealed classes.  if so, can I inherit a record type?  For example:

```
type person = {name:string; address:string}
type employee inherit person = {employeeId: string}
```

I have searching around the MSDN docs and language specs and I am not having any luck.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Offtopic but don't let employee inherit person :-)

Comment: I have this right now: employee{person:Person; etc..} which is proper according to Tomas P.  I was just seeing how else to do it. :-)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

F# records cannot be inherited - as Matthew mentions, they are compiled to sealed classes, but it is also an aspect of the F# types system which simply does not allow this.

In practice, you could go with an ordinary class declaration. This means that you won't be able to use the `{ person with ... }` syntax and you won't get the automatic structural equality, but it might make sense if you want to create C#-friendly code:

```
type Person(name:string) =
  member x.Name = name

type Employee(name:string, id:int) = 
  inherit Person(name)
  member x.ID = id
```

I think the preferred option would be to use *composition* rather than *inheritance* and make employee a record that is composed of some personal information and ID:

```
type PersonalInformation = { Name : string }

type Employee = 
  { Person : PersonalInformation 
    ID : int }
```

I probably would not make a *person* a part of *employee* (that does not feel right to me, but that is just an intuition), which is why I renamed it to `PersonalInformation` here.

I suppose another option would be to have `IPerson` as an interface and have a *record* `Employee` implementing the interface:

```
type IPerson = 
  abstract Name : string

type Employee = 
  { ID : int
    Name : string }
  interface IPerson with
    member x.Name = x.Name
```

Which one is the best really depends on the concrete thing that you're modelling. But I think interfaces and composition are generally preferred in F# :-)

Answer (score 9):

They are sealed classes, here's the first few lines of the class that's generated for `person`:

```
[CompilationMapping(SourceConstructFlags.RecordType)]
[Serializable]
public sealed class person 
: IEquatable<person>, 
  IStructuralEquatable, 
  IComparable<person>, 
  IComparable, 
  IStructuralComparable
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answer from Thomas, the F# documentation suggests to consider discriminated unions instead of inheritance:

> When you are creating object hierarchies, consider using a
> discriminated union instead of inheritance. Discriminated unions can
> also model varied behavior of different objects that share a common
> overall type. A single discriminated union can often eliminate the
> need for a number of derived classes that are minor variations of each
> other.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/inheritance#alternatives-to-inheritance

Reasons to avoid abstract classes are

- The design principle "favor composition over inheritance"
- That Domain Driven Design does not like things which do not exist in the real world.

Some example code how a User can be modelled:

```
type PersonalInformation = {
  Name: string }

type EmployeeId = EmployeeId of string

type GuestId = GuestId of string

type EmployeeData = {
  Id: EmployeeId
  PersonalInformation: PersonalInformation }

type GuestData = {
  Id: GuestId
  PersonalInformation: PersonalInformation }

type User =
  | Employee of EmployeeData
  | DisabledEmployee of EmployeeData
  | Guest of GuestData
```

Another example with 2 hierarchy levels of discriminated unions:

```
type EnabledUser =
  | Employee of EmployeeData
  | Guest of GuestData

type DisabledUser =
  | DisabledEmployee of EmployeeData
  | DisabledGuest of GuestData

type User =
  | EnabledUser of EnabledUser
  | DisabledUser of DisabledUser
```